# Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, embedded-linux

I am working on custom embedded Linux distribution on [P2020RDB-PCA board](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/qoriq-platforms/p-series/p2020-reference-design-board:P2020RDB) and I've got stuck on following errors at boot time:

```
EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 179:1.
devtmpfs: error mounting -2
Freeing unused kernel memory: 272K (c07cc000 - c0810000)
Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda #1
Call Trace:
[ef04de70] [c000707c] show_stack+0x44/0x16c (unreliable)
[ef04deb0] [c05f4604] dump_stack+0x78/0xa0
[ef04dec0] [c05f21dc] panic+0xdc/0x208
[ef04df20] [c000295c] kernel_init+0x174/0x178
[ef04df40] [c000f224] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x5c/0x64
```

Here is full boot log:

```
U-Boot 2013.01-00115-g831b30d (Jun 14 2013 - 21:48:56)

CPU0:  P2020E, Version: 2.1, (0x80ea0021)
Core:  E500, Version: 5.1, (0x80211051)
Clock Configuration:
       CPU0:1200 MHz, CPU1:1200 MHz, 
       CCB:600  MHz,
       DDR:400  MHz (800 MT/s data rate) (Asynchronous), LBC:37.500 MHz
L1:    D-cache 32 kB enabled
       I-cache 32 kB enabled
Board: P2020RDB-PCA CPLD: V4.2 PCBA: V4.0
rom_loc: nor upper bank
SD/MMC : 4-bit Mode
eSPI : Enabled
I2C:   ready
SPI:   ready
DRAM:  Detected UDIMM 
1 GiB (DDR3, 64-bit, CL=6, ECC off)
Flash: 16 MiB
L2:    512 KB enabled
NAND:  128 MiB
MMC:  FSL_SDHC: 0
PCIe1: Root Complex of mini PCIe SLOT, no link, regs @ 0xffe0a000
PCIe1: Bus 00 - 00
PCIe2: Root Complex of PCIe SLOT, x1, regs @ 0xffe09000
  02:00.0     - 1095:3132 - Mass storage controller
PCIe2: Bus 01 - 02
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   eTSEC2 is in sgmii mode.
uploading VSC7385 microcode from ef000000
PHY reset timed out
eTSEC1, eTSEC2, eTSEC3
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Device: FSL_SDHC
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SL08G 
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 2.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 7.4 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
4275699 bytes read in 240 ms (17 MiB/s)
13899 bytes read in 49 ms (276.4 KiB/s)
WARNING: adjusting available memory to 30000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 01000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda
   Created:      2016-12-12  17:39:15 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    4275635 Bytes = 4.1 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00c00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x00c00000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 03ff9000, end 03fff64a ... OK
WARNING: could not find compatible node fsl-usb2-dr: FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND.
Using P2020RDB-PC machine description
Memory CAM mapping: 256/256/256 Mb, residual: 256Mb
Linux version 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda (emsydev@vmworkstation) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Dec 12 18:37:14 CET 2016
CPU maps initialized for 1 thread per core
bootconsole [udbg0] enabled
setup_arch: bootmem
mpc85xx_rdb_setup_arch()
mpc85xx_qe_init: Could not find Quicc Engine node
MPC85xx RDB board from Freescale Semiconductor
arch: exit
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x00000000-0x2fffffff]
  Normal   empty
  HighMem  [mem 0x30000000-0x3fffffff]
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x00000000-0x3fffffff]
MMU: Allocated 1088 bytes of context maps for 255 contexts
PERCPU: Embedded 7 pages/cpu @c119a000 s7072 r8192 d13408 u32768
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260608
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=3 console=ttyS0,115200
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 963620K/1048576K available (6104K kernel code, 320K rwdata, 1864K rodata, 272K init, 1218K bss, 84956K reserved, 262136K highmem)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xfff5f000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xffc00000..0xffe00000  : highmem PTEs
  * 0xffbfc000..0xffc00000  : early ioremap
  * 0xf1000000..0xffbfc000  : vmalloc & ioremap
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
        RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
mpic: Setting up MPIC " OpenPIC  " version 1.2 at ffe40000, max 2 CPUs
mpic: ISU size: 256, shift: 8, mask: ff
mpic: Initializing for 256 sources
mpc85xx_rdb_pic_init: Could not find qe-ic node
clocksource: timebase mult[d555555] shift[24] registered
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
mpic: requesting IPIs...
Brought up 2 CPUs
devtmpfs: initialized
NET: Registered protocol family 16

Found FSL PCI host bridge at 0x00000000ffe09000. Firmware bus number: 0->1
PCI host bridge /pcie@ffe09000 (primary) ranges:
 MEM 0x00000000a0000000..0x00000000bfffffff -> 0x00000000a0000000 
  IO 0x00000000ffc10000..0x00000000ffc1ffff -> 0x0000000000000000
/pcie@ffe09000: PCICSRBAR @ 0xfff00000
Found FSL PCI host bridge at 0x00000000ffe0a000. Firmware bus number: 0->0
PCI host bridge /pcie@ffe0a000  ranges:
 MEM 0x0000000080000000..0x000000009fffffff -> 0x0000000080000000 
  IO 0x00000000ffc00000..0x00000000ffc0ffff -> 0x0000000000000000
/pcie@ffe0a000: PCICSRBAR @ 0xfff00000
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
fsl-pci ffe09000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xa0000000-0xbfffffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: ignoring class 0x0b2000 (doesn't match header type 01)
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff]
fsl-pci ffe0a000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0001:02
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [io  0x20000-0x2ffff] (bus address [0x0000-0xffff])
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [mem 0x80000000-0x9fffffff]
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [bus 02-ff]
pci 0001:02:00.0: ignoring class 0x0b2000 (doesn't match header type 01)
pci 0001:02:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
pci 0001:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 9: can't assign mem pref (size 0x100000)
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xa0080000-0xa00fffff pref]
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xbfffffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: Some PCI device resources are unassigned, try booting with pci=realloc
pci 0001:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
pci 0001:02:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x20000-0x2ffff]
pci 0001:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0x9fffffff]
fsl-l2ctlr ffe20000.l2-cache-controller: Entire L2 as cache, provide valid sram address and size
fsl-l2ctlr: probe of ffe20000.l2-cache-controller failed with error -22
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
Freescale Elo series DMA driver
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #0 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 76
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #1 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 77
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #2 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 78
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #3 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 79
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #0 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 20
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #1 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 21
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #2 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 22
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #3 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 23
qe_init: Could not find Quicc Engine node
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
Switched to clocksource timebase
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
TCP: reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Freescale PMC driver
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(0.308:1): initialized
bounce pool size: 64 pages
HugeTLB registered 1 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 4 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 16 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 64 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 256 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 1 GB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Key type id_resolver registered
Key type id_legacy registered
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O].
jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) �Ʃ 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
msgmni has been set to 1500
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 2 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xffe04500 (irq = 42, base_baud = 37500000) is a 16550A
console [ttyS0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
console [ttyS0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
serial8250.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xffe04600 (irq = 42, base_baud = 37500000) is a 16550A
Generic non-volatile memory driver v1.1
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
nbd: registered device at major 43
st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
pci 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0106 -> 0107)
scsi0 : sata_sil24
scsi1 : sata_sil24
ata1: SATA max UDMA/100 host m128@0xa0000000 port 0xa0004000 irq 24
ata2: SATA max UDMA/100 host m128@0xa0000000 port 0xa0006000 irq 24
ef000000.nor: Found 1 x16 devices at 0x0 in 16-bit bank. Manufacturer ID 0x000001 Chip ID 0x002101
Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query Table at 0x0040
  Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query version 1.5.
number of CFI chips: 1
5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device ef000000.nor
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "ef000000.nor":
0x000000000000-0x000000040000 : "NOR Vitesse-7385 Firmware"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000040000-0x000000080000 : "NOR DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000080000-0x000000500000 : "NOR Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000500000-0x000000ec0000 : "NOR JFFS2 Root File System"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000ec0000-0x000001000000 : "NOR U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
ONFI param page 0 valid
ONFI flash detected
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xf1 (Micron MT29F1G08ABAEAWP), 128MiB, page size: 2048, OOB size: 64
Bad block table found at page 65472, version 0x01
Bad block table found at page 65408, version 0x01
6 ofpart partitions found on MTD device ff800000.flash
Creating 6 MTD partitions on "ff800000.flash":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "NAND U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000100000-0x000000200000 : "NAND DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000200000-0x000000600000 : "NAND Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000600000-0x000000a00000 : "NAND Compressed RFS Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000a00000-0x000001100000 : "NAND JFFS2 Root File System"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000001100000-0x000002000000 : "NAND Writable User area"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
eLBC NAND device at 0xff800000, bank 1
fsl_espi ffe07000.spi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
m25p80 spi32766.0: found s25fl128s, expected m25p80
m25p80 spi32766.0: s25fl128s (16384 Kbytes)
5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device spi32766.0
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "spi32766.0":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "SPI U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000100000-0x000000180000 : "SPI DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000180000-0x000000580000 : "SPI Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000580000-0x000000980000 : "SPI Compressed RFS Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000980000-0x000001000000 : "SPI JFFS2 RFS"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
fsl_espi ffe07000.spi: at 0xf10e8000 (irq = 59)
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed
libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7a
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7b
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7c
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
ucc_geth_driver: QE UCC Gigabit Ethernet Controller
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2013 Intel Corporation.
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: irq 28, io mem 0xffe22000
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
i2c /dev entries driver
mpc-i2c ffe03000.i2c: timeout 1000000 us
mpc-i2c ffe03100.i2c: timeout 1000000 us
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
/soc@ffe00000/sdhc@2e000: voltage-ranges unspecified
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: SDHCI controller on ffe2e000.sdhc [ffe2e000.sdhc] using DMA
talitos ffe30000.crypto: hwrng
talitos ffe30000.crypto: max_xor_srcs 6
talitos ffe30000.crypto: fsl,sec3.1 algorithms registered in /proc/crypto
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
usbhid: USB HID core driver
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
snd-soc-p1022ds: missing/invalid global utils node
ipip: IPv4 over IPv4 tunneling driver
TCP: cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 10
sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
Key type dns_resolver registered
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
/home/emsydev/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/build_p2020rdb/tmp/work-shared/p2020rdb/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device)
snd-soc-p1022rdk: missing/invalid global utils node
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Waiting 3 sec before mounting root device...
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using fsl-ehci
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL08G 7.40 GiB 
 mmcblk0: p1 p2
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 179:1.
devtmpfs: error mounting -2
Freeing unused kernel memory: 272K (c07cc000 - c0810000)
Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda #1
Call Trace:
[ef04de70] [c000707c] show_stack+0x44/0x16c (unreliable)
[ef04deb0] [c05f4604] dump_stack+0x78/0xa0
[ef04dec0] [c05f21dc] panic+0xdc/0x208
[ef04df20] [c000295c] kernel_init+0x174/0x178
[ef04df40] [c000f224] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x5c/0x64
Rebooting in 180 seconds..
```

The structure of sd card, which I am in process preparing of, has two partitons:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x90d4d9aa

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          2016  2099167  2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       2099200 15523839 13424640  6.4G 83 Linux
```

On **/dev/sdb1**, there is **boot** directory with **uImage** and **device tree**:

```
.:
total 28K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Dec 15 07:59 .
4.0K drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 4.0K Dec 15 09:13 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Dec 15 08:08 boot
 16K drwx------  2 root root  16K Dec 15 07:52 lost+found

./boot:
total 4.2M
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 15 08:08 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 15 07:59 ..
 16K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14K Dec 15 08:08 dtb_file
4.1M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M Dec 15 08:00 uImage

./lost+found:
total 20K
 16K drwx------ 2 root root  16K Dec 15 07:52 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 15 07:59 ..
```

On **/dev/sdb2**, there is **rootfs**, which **.tar.gz** was build using [Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) and **Board SDK**:

```
total 84K

    4.0K drwxr-xr-x  18 root root 4.0K Dec 14 14:18 .
    4.0K drwxr-x---+  4 root root 4.0K Dec 15 09:13 ..
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 bin
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 boot
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 dev
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x  21 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 etc
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 home
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 lib
       0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   12 Dec 13 10:04 linuxrc -> /bin/busybox
     16K drwx------   2 root root  16K Dec 14 14:09 lost+found
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 media
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 mnt
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 proc
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 run
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 sbin
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 sys
    4.0K drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 14:29 tmp
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4.0K Dec 12 20:35 usr
    4.0K drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4.0K Dec 13 10:04 var
```

What am I missing so the boot process fails with these two errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel logs contain the line:

```
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext2 ......
```

meaning that it is **mounting the first SD card partition as root**. Since your rootfs is on the second partition then it should be changed to `/dev/mmcblk0p2`. You should be able to set this in your U-Boot environment.

Comment: How do I setup parameters for U-Boot, I mean which file should I add/edit for *kernel command line* parameter editing?

Comment: Kernel parameters are passed through U-Boot environment variables. If you break into the U-Boot prompt and give the `printenv` command in the output there should be an environment variable called `bootargs`. Then you can use the `setenv` command to change its value to point to the correct rootfs partition

Comment: ok, but where do I configure `U-Boot` in offline mode, before boot, I want to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

In U-Boot Enviroment, I've trapped autoboot and set **root** parameter to *mmcblk0p2*:
`setenv bootargs=root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=3 console=ttyS0,115200`
and then saved changed paramater via
`saveenv` and restarted system. Now it boots!
I was **not aware** of `saveenv` command.